# Category not found in Cocoapods library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am releasing a new version of my CocoaPods library. In this version I included the [UIDevice-Hardware.h](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) category.

I am aware of the use of the `-ObjC` flag to import categories in static libraries. In `Build Phases -> Copy Headers`, `UIDevice-Hardware.h` is in 'Project'.

When I run `pod lib lint --no-clean`, I thought the `-ObjC` flag would be set, but I get the error:

```
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]    
TCBlobDownload/TCBlobDownload/TCBlobDownload/TCBlobDownloader.m:16:9: fatal error: 
'UIDevice-Hardware.h' file not found

Pods project available at `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj` for inspection.
```

So I added this line in my `.podspec`:

```
spec.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-ObjC -all_load -force_load' }
```

Yeah, all three flags, just to be sure.

And I still got the same error. I checked the said `Pods.xcodeproj` and in it's target, `Other Linker Flags` is empty, no `-ObjC` or anything else. But the `.xcconfig` files have my flags defined in the `.podspec`... I don't know where to go from that.

**The library builds well when I import it in a test project in which I set the flag. How can I make it lint with CocoaPods?**

Comment: Is the header file picked up by your glob to say which files to include in the pod?

Comment: @Paul.s Thanks for this comment, it just helped me to solve it. Since I placed this category in a subfolder, I replaced `spec.source_files = 'TCBlobDownload/TCBlobDownload/*.{h,m}'` with `TCBlobDownload/TCBlobDownload/**/*.{h,m}` and it's fixed. Dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the header file picked up by your glob to say which files to include in the pod? Sounds like the spec simply isn't including the file.