# CocoaPod with category not available at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, cocoapods

I know the same kind of issue has [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271300/category-not-found-in-cocoapods-library) [been](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/XTl58lokd-E) [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998483/objective-c-category-causing-unrecognized-selector), but I think I face another one.

I created the CocoaPod called [NSURLSession+PromiseKit](https://github.com/jschmid/NSURLSession-PromiseKit) to allow using PromiseKit with NSURLSession.

I have the definition:

```c
@implementation NSURLSession (PromiseKit)

- (PMKPromise *)promiseDataTaskWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [PMKPromise ...];
}

@end
```

And the code sample:

```c
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."];
[session promiseDataTaskWithURL:url].then( ^(NSData *data) {
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", data);
}).catch( ^(NSError *e) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", e);
});
```

works on iOS 8, but not on iOS 7. I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFURLSession **promiseDataTaskWithURL**:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c236720'

Now of course I though that the category was not loaded so I added this line to the [podspec](https://github.com/jschmid/NSURLSession-PromiseKit/blob/0.3.0/NSURLSession-PromiseKit.podspec) to make sure that the code is loaded:

```rb
s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-ObjC -all_load' }
```

**But it does not work better.**

So I added a line to the [category file](https://github.com/jschmid/NSURLSession-PromiseKit/blob/0.3.0/Pod/Classes/NSURLSession%2BPromiseKit.m):

```
+ (void)load {
    NSLog(@"loaded");
}
```

To my surprise the `load` method is called, which means that the code is indeed loaded. So **why is the category method not found while executing if the code is loaded?**

Comment: That `-force_load` flag needs a parameter, which will cause warnings at the very least.

Comment: You are right, I am mistaken here. The code is still loaded without it so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as often, posting the question lead me to the answer.

It has been [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629682/ios-nsurlsession-category-methods-not-being-found-at-runtime) that NSURLSession does not support categories.

- In iOS 7, the underlying `NSURLSession` class is `__NSCFURLSession`, which does not support the categories.
- In iOS 8, the underlying class is `__NSURLSessionLocal`, which does support categories.

My solution, although cringeworthy is to replace:

```
@implementation NSURLSession (PromiseKit)
```

By:

```
@implementation NSObject (PromiseKit)
```

**Only on the implementation file**. This will prevent a Pod user to mistakenly use the method with something else than a `NSURLSession` object. However, it does not prevent him to play other tricks to make the thing crash...